# Delphi program don't have error but don't show the result of callback function

Tags: c++, delphi

I want to convert c++ code to Delphi. The c++ code is getting stream from camera(Hikvision).I use a dll in my program, I am using this function in dll:

**c++ code:**

```
NET_DVR_API LONG __stdcall NET_DVR_RealPlay_V30(LONG lUserID, LPNET_DVR_CLIENTINFO lpClientInfo, void(CALLBACK *fRealDataCallBack_V30) (LONG lRealHandle, DWORD dwDataType, BYTE *pBuffer, DWORD dwBufSize, void* pUser) = NULL, void* pUser = NULL, BOOL bBlocked = FALSE);
```

**delphi code (that I convert):**

```
type
fRealDataCallBack_V30 =procedure(lRealHandle : LongInt; dwDataType: DWORD;pBuffer: PByte; dwBufSize: DWORD; dwUser: DWORD);stdcall;
function  NET_DVR_RealPlay_V30 ( lUserID: Longint; lpClientInfo: LPNET_DVR_CLIENTINFO; fRealDataCallBack_V30: fRealDataCallBack_V30; pUser: Pointer; bBlocked: Boolean): Longint;stdcall; external 'HCNetSDK.dll'name 'NET_DVR_RealPlay_V30';
```

That function needs callback function:
**c++ code :**

```
 void CALLBACK fRealDataCallBack(LONG lRealHandle, DWORD dwDataType, BYTE *pBuffer, DWORD dwBufSize, void* dwUser)
    {
        printf("\nhello");
    }
```

**Delphi code(that I convert):**

```
procedure RealDataCallBack(lRealHandle: Longint; dwDataType: Longword; pBuffer: LPByte; dwBufSize: Longword; pUser:Pointer);stdcall;
begin
 ShowMessage('hello');
end;
```

and use that callback function as a parameter in dll function:

**c++ code:**

```
NET_DVR_RealPlay_V30(lUserID,&client, fRealDataCallBack,NULL,false);
```

**delphi code (that I convert):**

```
NET_DVR_RealPlay_V30(iLoginID,@lpClientInfo,RealDataCallBack,nil,false);
```

my c++ code is work completely correctly,but my delphi code can't call callback function.

Comment: Why did you make dll functions methods of the form? Write them apart from the form class definition. Check whether these functions really have `stdcall` modifier.

Comment: @MBo , i make dll function in another unit not in part of form but don'show anything

Comment: You seem to have ignored most of the advice from previous questions. I for one am not interested in trying to help under those circumstances..

Comment: @DavidHeffernan,please help me, i really try to do your advice

Comment: The Delphi code you present does not compile. Your `NET_DVR_RealPlay_V30` accepts `LPNET_DVR_CLIENTINFO` but you pass `NET_DVR_CLIENTINFO`. You showed fake code. It's really no fun on our side. Can't you show a [mcve]? And what about your previous questions? We took time to provide correct answers, which were not accepted. In your first question you received two good answers. You have not voted, and have not accepted an answer. Perhaps you should visit the [help] and learn how to get more out of the site. It feels a little as though you just want us to do your job for you.

Comment: Then there's the fact that you pass different values to the function in the two programs. So it's perfectly plausible that they behave differently. Try to make a minimal example that is an exact translation of the C++ code. Don't bother with a GUI. Use a console app just as the C++ code does. Remember also that your header translation could be wrong for all we know. I appreciate that you have little clue as to what you are doing and are completely lost. But continuing to wander whilst lost is not productive. Concentrate on the small detail. Try to do one simple thing carefully.

Comment: "But continuing to wander whilst lost is not productive". Well, when you are going through hell, keep on going. <g> Fact is though that you are right. He seems to be only interested in getting his job done, and not in rewarding those who gave him their valueable time to answer his questions. And he doesn't seem to be able (or wanting) to actually follow advice. IOW, a [help vampire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire).

Comment: FWIW, it looks as if this is not even the full C++ code either. There is a `while(1);` but no `do`, and the call to `xxx_v30` is indented, so I assume there was a do-while loop. Also, `lUserID` is not declared anywhere, so it looks as if code has been cut from the demo as well. How can we help when even the demo is incomplete?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, my c++ code is true and run,my delphi code can login to camera but when recieve in call back function can't show anything, i traste my code i guess that is becuse of parameters of NET_DVR_RealPlay_V30 , but i don't konw where is my problem

Comment: @saharghodsbin: There is a `while(1);` which, as it is, and if it is not preceded by a `do` and a `break` inside the loop, will loop forever. That can not be the original code. Also `lUserID` is not declared anywhere. As I said: that *cannot be* the full original code.

Comment: FWIW, the C++ code sets all bytes in the structs to 0 (using `= {0};`) before they are used. You don't do that (you should use `FillChar` for that). And it is impossible to see if your translation of the functions is correct, and if the C++ names are not decorated/mangled. Try to do what the previous answers told you and then come back. Also there is no need to use pointers and `New`. Just use the structs directly. Why don't you first try to copy the C++ demo code exactly, but then in Delphi, and then run that? Show the original C++ code (yours isn't) and the Delphi translation.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, I put compeletely c++ code in my post, and you said 'Why don't you first try to copy the C++ demo code exactly, but then in Delphi, and then run that?' what is that mean?

Comment: Translate the C++ demo (console) program to Delphi 1:1 and then see if that works. Then you can go and use your own code. And the C++ code you show is not complete, that is for sure. Some lines are missing.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, how can I translate the C++ demo (console) program to Delphi 1:1?